# Weird Issue with Laravel Slack Notification

Tags: laravel, notifications, listener, webhooks, slack-api

I am new in Laravel and I am trying to send Slack Notification each time an order is placed. For testing, I used my Incoming Webhook. Now when I am changing the webhook to clients slack webhook. Its still sending the notification to old webhook. 
Can you help me sort this out?

This is my Listener

```
 public function handle(OrderConfirmed $event)
    {
         $admin=User::find(73);
    $user=User::find($event->order->user_id);
    $order=Order::find($event->order->id);
    Notification::send(User::find(73),(new \App\Notifications\PaymentProcessedNot($user,$order)));
    }
```

This is my PaymentProcessedNot class

```
class PaymentProcessedNot extends Notification implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Queueable;
    public $user;
    public $order;

    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(\App\User $user,\App\Order $order)
    {
        $this->user=$user;
        $this->order=$order;
    }

    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['slack'];
    }


    public function toSlack($notifiable){
        return (new SlackMessage)
            ->success()
            ->content('A new Payment was just processed.')
            ->attachment(function ($attachment){
                $attachment->title('Order : '. $this->order->order_id)
                    ->fields([
                        'Amount' => ' ₹'. number_format($this->order->amount,2),
                        'From' => $this->user->name,
                        'Payment Mode' => strtoupper($this->order->payment_mode)
                    ]);
            });
    }


}
```

This is my User.php

```
public function routeNotificationForSlack()
    {
        return 'new_slack_incoming_webhook';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If your using .env you should clear the cache!

Just checking this is actually the url right?
return 'new_slack_incoming_webhook';

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56209548/laravel-slack-on-demand-notification-where-to-set-the-webhook